# Honeywell hz322 heat pump with aux heat

Tags: hvac, heat-pump, heat, zoned-heating

I get heat and aux separately but not together.  I checked the 322 and it's calling for both, but only heat light is on.  I only have w1 wired... Is this the problem?  I see is says to tie w1 and w2 together?  Could this be it?

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your indoor unit, or its make/model for that matter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up being W1 and w2 needed tried together on the thermo side and equipment side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).